# Can wee bonnie lass be used for a 2-year-old girl?

Tags: word-usage

I know what wee bonnie lass means, but my question is can we use it for kids?

I heard that it can only be used when complimenting a girl, as in boys use it, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Is it *wee* or *bonnie* or *lass* that you think can't be used on kids?

Comment: What I heard is that it can only be used when complimenting a girl, as in boys use it. I might be wrong as well

Comment: **lass** signifies the female gender, **lassie** is the diminutive

Comment: Bonnie (pretty) Wee (little) Lass (girl)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. In fact using *wee* would make me think you were probably talking about a child, though it could be used for a petite woman. *Bonnie* can be used on children or adults. *Lass* can also be used on children or adults. I would tend to think of *lass* as being 10-year-old or more, but *wee lass* could be younger than that.

It does sound slightly more natural to me to say *bonnie wee lass* rather than *wee bonnie lass*, but both would be understood.

Finally, be careful about using dialect words like this unless you're specifically speaking to people from that area. "Wee bonnie lass" would be understood by most British English speakers, but would still sound a bit unusual coming from a non-Scot. For example, as an English person living in Scotland, I do use some Scots terms when talking to my (mostly Scottish) friends, but if I were to talk to my (English) family with those terms, they'd probably think it was a bit weird and might tease me a bit. As a non-native speaker, you have the added risk that people may think you don't even know it's a dialect phrase.

Comment: +1, in part for your cautionary note at the end. This expression would sound more comical than serious in the U.S.

Comment: Yes, dialect words are a danger zone!  Unless you're using them ironically, which doesn't sound to be the case in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Bonnie wee lassie...heard it all my life..used on all the wains in scotland.. auch your a bonnie wee lassie..

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether you're saying this phrase *can* or *can't* be used for kids.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Janet actually **does** say it's appropriate for kids: [wains](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wain), you just don't speak Scots, down vote is unfair

Comment: @Peter: I'm a native American English speaker who's read lots of books in all English dialects (including Scottish, modern and period); if I can't understand their point, I consider it entirely fair to assume non-native speakers won't either and downvote accordingly.

Comment: Also "your a bonnie..."  - isn't that supposed to be "you're a bonnie..."? We need to take a little more care when we're writing for folks still learning English. I think the Scottish perspective is interesting, and that complete sentences, punctuated and spelled correctly would go a long way toward making this a better answer.